# psycopg2 : module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL in Python using psycopg2, and I'm passing my connection parameters to the `psycopg2.connect()` function as follows:

```py
session = psycopg2.connect(
    host="hostvalue", database="db_value", user="username", password="password"
)
```

But this is throwing the following error:

```
module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'connect'
```

I've already installed psycopg2-binary on my mac, as is evident when I try installing it with pip again:

```
$ pip3 install psycopg2-binary
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.8.4)
```

I really don't know why I'm seeing this error. Could someone please help me out here.

Comment: Try uninstalling psycopg2-binary, and installing it afresh, with the --no-cache-dir option, too. Something similar happened to me with the face_recognition library some weeks back. I did what @dewald-abrie suggests in you do in their answer, and found out the offending method was really not there. (Deleting and then) recreating my virtual environment solved the problem for me.

Comment: Are you sure that the program is being run with the same Python installation as the one with the library?

Comment: I just un-installed and installed psycopg2 again and it is working now .. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try calling `dir` on the module and print the output like so:

```
import psycopg2, pprint
pprint.pprint(dir(psycopg2))
['BINARY',
 'Binary',
 'DATETIME',
 'DataError',
 'DatabaseError',
 'Date',
 'DateFromTicks',
 'Error',
 'IntegrityError',
 'InterfaceError',
 'InternalError',
 'NUMBER',
 'NotSupportedError',
 'OperationalError',
 'ProgrammingError',
 'ROWID',
 'STRING',
 'Time',
 'TimeFromTicks',
 'Timestamp',
 'TimestampFromTicks',
 'Warning',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__libpq_version__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '__warningregistry__',
 '_connect',
 '_ext',
 '_json',
 '_psycopg',
 '_range',
 'apilevel',
 'connect',
 'extensions',
 'paramstyle',
 'threadsafety',
 'tz',
 'warn']
```

You should see the `'connect'` method in the list as shown above.

Comment: I tried running below command in python3 and I don't see 'connect' in the output , is this issue with the psycopg2 installation ? whereas when I run the command by opening python shell I do see "connect" in the output ..

python3
Python 3.8.1 (v3.8.1:1b293b6006, Dec 18 2019, 14:08:53) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2,pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dir(psycopg2))
['__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__']
>>>

Comment: I just un-installed and installed psycopg2 again and it is working now .. Thank you all for your help